# Expo + firebase@9.0.1/9.0.0: @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo, node-modules

I just updated my Expo mobile application from firebase@9.0.0-beta.7 to firebase@9.0.1 and came across following error: `@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds`.

I'm running mobile app in Expo Go with android studio emulator.
In application Auth works fine as I can log user in and out but when I try to do something with Firestore I get following error: `Failed to get document because the client is offline.`
This happens for example in basic getDoc() function

```
const dbRef = doc(db, 'exampleColletion', 'id');
    await getDoc(dbRef).then(document => {
      const information = document.data();
      if (information !== undefined) {
        eventsRetreived(information);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      eventsRetreived(err);
      console.log(err.message)
    })
```

I have made some test by using either `firebase@9.0.1` or `firebase@9.0.0` but in both I face the same problem but in `firebase@9.0.0-beta.7` everything is working fine (and I'm not changing any code but changing only the version of firebase).

If more code or information is needed plz tell what I need to add and I will edit this post as needed.

**EDIT**
Found related github issue but even is closed I'm still facing the issue after testing firebase@9.0.2
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5402

**EDIT2**
Seems like issue is appearing in Expo v. 42. At the moment Expo support by default compat version of Firebase so the solution at the moment is to use `firebase@9.0.0-beta.7` or compat version that is supported by Expo and is installed through `expo install firebase`

Comment: Did you try using [Node.js SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)? Do you still get these errors there?

Comment: @FaridShumbar I have another Expo project that contains Firebase functions that uses Firebase Admin Node.js SDK and it works fine. Also that project uses `firebase@9.0.1` and it has no problem when Firestore is called.

Comment: BUT.. that project uses expo-web and is using `firebase@9.01` in web enviroment (but setting the config in same way still as in mobile project). I don't know if this affects things at all but just mentioning.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue while using Expo v. 42.

Comment: @MaxFahl interesting. We probably need to wait until expo v. 43 is released where modular firebase could be used and at while waiting either use ´firebase@9.0.0-beta.7´ or compat version that comes by `expo install firebase`

Comment: Yes. I'm going with "9.0.0-beta.7" for now, since I'm mostly using it for a hobby project of mine. Thanks for pointing that version out.

Comment: Having the same issue on expo 43 beta, even though the tell you to use firebase 9.

Comment: @MaxFahl Did you use `firebase@9.0.2` that is installed when running `expo upgrade` and is told to be used in Expo v43 beta documentation: > Recommended firebase version is now 9.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get it to work by using this setting:

```
initializeFirestore(firebaseInstance.current, {
  // @ts-ignore
  useFetchStreams: false,
  cacheSizeBytes: 100000000,
})
```

Seems iOS does not want to play nice with the Fetch API, using `useFetchStreams` falls back to using `XMLHttpRequest` instead, which seems to do the trick for me at the moment. I'm on firebase `9.0.2`.